# How does this stepper motor work?

Tags: stepper-motor

I found this stepper motor, it seems like a NEMA 24, with four pins.

I connected it to a driver (which formaly ran a NEMA 17), and at most it just makes a click sound and nothing else. I opened it up and noticed that while there are four pins, the third and fourth are intentionaly connecected so basically all coils make conatact with each other. How does that make sense? What kind of motor is this and how do I use it?

[image]

Comment: nema stepper motors tend to have a consistent method by which they function.  i suspect you could search the nets.  magnetic fields in the stator coils will, when energized, attract or repel (depending on direction of current) the permanent magnets in the rotor.  As to how it makes sense... check your motor while it is disconnected and properly identify the coils accounting for induced readings from other coils.

Comment: It seems a three phases motor ... Where did you get it ?

Comment: https://elabz.com/brushless-dc-motor-with-arduino/

Comment: poles divisible by three, three connections, it's a 3 phase motor, so a BLDC and needs an ESC

Answer (score 3):

It's a BLDC motor (brushless DC) and requires a suitable driver (typically three half-bridges controlled by an MCU).

Some drivers require sensors (eg. Hall) and some are sensorless (they infer position from back-EMF).

Comment: A BLDC motor would have permanent magnets on the rotor. This one does not appear to have any permanent magnets on the rotor. It really appears to be a reluctance type stepper motor.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely 3 phase but the teeth suggest variable reluctance rather than the usual permanent magnet. (If so, it should spin quite freely without cogging when unpowered).

As one electrical revolution advances it by 1 tooth position, it'll turn slowly. And that probably means there isn't enough back EMF for sensorless (closed loop) control.

So you probably want to drive it open loop like a stepper, but with 3 phases (either sine or 6 step trapezoidal) like a BLDC.In that case, open loop means generate the 3 phases without regard to the motor position, and hope the motor keeps up.